# Remove property of node without know name of property via Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I created many node with a few property has value is NULL (maybe its value is "") and now I want to remove all that property. I can't remove step by step property with its property name.
Update 1:
When I call `match(u:User) return properties(u)` on Browser, it return that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt0NW.png)

Comment: `null` will never be a property value in Neo4j, this indicates non-existence. Can you show the query you're using to detect these problematic properties?

Comment: Sorry. Its value is "" with string value. When i get property on browser, it return property is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, okay, these are empty string values, as you guessed.

We'll need a graph-wide query that will find nodes with empty-string properties. This will have to touch all properties of all nodes, so it may be expensive on a larger graph.

As for removing these dynamically, Cypher doesn't have great support for that kind of operation. If you can install [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/), however, then we can easily clear out these properties.

The approach I'm using in this query is to use a filter/extract on the keys of a node, and to create a pairing of a key to `null` as a two-element list for all keys with empty string values.

We'll then use `apoc.map.fromPairs()` to generate a map of those keys to null values, then use the `+=` operation on the node, which will apply all these map values to the node's properties, effectively removing those properties since setting a property to `null` is the same as removing it.

```
MATCH (u:User) // if you want this run for all nodes, remove the label
WITH u, [key in keys(u) WHERE u[key] = '' | [key, null]] as nullifiers
WHERE size(nullifiers) <> 0
WITH u, apoc.map.fromPairs(nullifiers) as nullifyMap
SET u += nullifyMap
```

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this looking for elegant solutions. To optimize a query like this, even more, you can wrap it in an APOC procedure for batching in parallel like this:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"MATCH (u:User) RETURN u",
"WITH u, [key in keys(u) WHERE o[key] = '' | [key, null]] as nullifiers WHERE size(nullifiers) <> 0 WITH u, apoc.map.fromPairs(nullifiers) as nullifyMap SET u += nullifyMap",
{batchSize:30000, parallel:true, iterateList:true});
```